# Как получить имя файла в gulp.task("watch")

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

У меня есть следующая задача: При удалении картинки из раздела `/src/blocks/nav/assets/img/1.jpg` я хочу удалить аналогичную картинку в `/src/img/`

Для этого у меня есть следующая прослушка события:

```
gulp.watch('src/blocks/**/**/*.{png,gif,jpg,jpeg,svg}', ['min-images'])
.on('change', function (event) {
    if(event.type === 'deleted') {
        console.log("ИМЯ ФАЙЛА!");
    }
});
```

Как мне в `console.log("имя файла!");` - вывести имя файла, который только что удалили?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно можно вывести используя параметры коллбэка. Если не получится, то необходимо будет свериться с документацией по используемой версии gulp.

```
var watcher = gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', gulp.parallel('concat', 'uglify'));
watcher.on('change', function(path, stats) {
  console.log('File ' + path + ' was changed');
});

watcher.on('unlink', function(path) {
  console.log('File ' + path + ' was removed');
});
```

Для справки [gulp API](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#fn-1) и [пример удаления из документации](https://gulpjs.org/recipes/handling-the-delete-event-on-watch.html).
Пример для gulp 3.9:

```
var watcher = gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', ['uglify','reload']);
watcher.on('change', function(event) {
  console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
});
```

Comment: это актуально для версии 4.x, для версии 3.9.x `event.path` будет содержать путь к файлу.

Comment: у меня как раз 3.9.3 кажется

Comment: Вот [документация watch для 3.9](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb)